# Single quotation marks in variable call not allowing search in multiple paths

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to filter some logs and for this I'm using the command below.

```
eval metrics=($(ssh -q XXXXXX@$server grep  -H '' $path | sed 's/-\|log:/|/g' | sed 's/CAM01CPD|\|CAM02BPD|\|XXXX|\|//g' | sed 's;/;|;g' | awk -F\| '{ printf "%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|", $11, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23; if ($26 != "") printf "%s\n", $26; else printf "%s\n", $25;}'))
```

And the $path in the command above is this:

```
path="/logs/XXX/production/.snapshot/ifs-QBA_LS1-VAULT_30Day_2016-06-29_19-01/jboss/pvmk*/xxx-production-xxx*/AppLog/xxx-production-xxx*-apimetrics.log"
```

The problem is that as we have multiples paths I have to use the * in the path to filter all of the directories, but in the script this * is being interpreted as part of the path because of those single quotation marks.

Output from bash -x:

```
++ ssh -q xxxxxx@xxxxxx grep -H '' '/logs/xxx/production/.snapshot/ifs-QBA_LS1-VAULT_30Day_2016-06-29_19-01/jboss/pvmk*/xxx-production-xxx*/AppLog/xxx-production-xxx*-apimetrics.log'
++ sed 's/CAM01CPD|\|CAM02BPD|\|XXXX|\|//g'
++ sed 's;/;|;g'
++ awk '-F|' '{ printf "%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|", $11, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23; if ($26 != "") printf "%s\n", $26; else printf "%s\n", $25;}'
++ sed 's/-\|log:/|/g'
+ eval 'metrics=()'
++ metrics=()
```

How do I run this command inside the Shellscript without those quotation marks so I can explore all the paths?

Comment: The single quotes you mention, are those the ones that aren't around the `$path` variable when calling `grep` in your example?

Comment: Most likely explanation: the globbing pattern didn't match anything and was left as-is. The single quotes in the output are an unrelated artifact of `set -x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>See below for the *robust* way to pass globbing results to an external command, using an *array*.</sup>

The likely cause of your problem is that **your glob doesn't match anything, and is therefore left as-is**.

As the OP points out in a comment, the reasons was that the glob was expanded on the *machine running the command* rather than on the *server targeted with the `ssh` command*.

To verify, use your pattern *unquoted* on the command line and see what you get:

```
echo /logs/XXX/production/.snapshot/ifs-QBA_LS1-VAULT_30Day_2016-06-29_19-01/jboss/pvmk*/xxx-production-xxx*/AppLog/xxx-production-xxx*-apimetrics.log
```

If you get the *same* string - with the `*` chars. - back, you know that nothing matched.

If you run `shopt -s nullglob` beforehand, the outcome will be more obvious: if nothing matches, *nothing* will be echoed.

Using `shopt -s nullglob` or even `shopt -s failglob` in your script will allow you to detect up front if you have any matching files.

---

The **single quotes in the output are an artifact of `set -x`, and they are unrelated to what, if any, quoting you used in your command.**

`set -x` shows you the *already expanded* values - which are therefore all *literals* at that point - and *selectively single-quotes* them if they contain so-called shell metacharacters (such as spaces) or globbing chars.

Since your glob didn't match anything and was therefore left as-is as a literal, `set -x` enclosed it in single quotes due to the presence of `*` chars.

---

For a robust solution (notably, one that works with filenames with embedded spaces), you need to collect the globbing results in an *array* first, and pass the array to `grep`:

```
# Collect matching paths - note that the path is _unquoted_ to ensure
# that globbing is applied (you can selectively quote _literal_ substrings,
# if needed).
paths=( /logs/XXX/production/.snapshot/ifs-QBA_LS1-VAULT_30Day_2016-06-29_19-01/jboss/pvmk*/xxx-production-xxx*/AppLog/xxx-production-xxx*-apimetrics.log )

# Error out, if nothing matched.
(( ${#paths[@]} > 0 )) || { echo "No matching files." >&2; exit 1; }

# Now, pass the array to `grep`, which will expand it to
# individual filename parameters:
... grep -H '' "${paths[@]}" | ...
```

Comment: Such a great explanation. I understood it now. As these directories are other servers I had to do path=$(ssh -q user@server "ls /my/path*/lala.log".
Thanks a lot!